# How to fix ajax issue with not displaying in console?

Tags: javascript, java, ajax

I have a simple ajax call in my Java spring boot application that calls a method in the controller and then returns the value to the front-end console. However, when I run the code it runs with a status of `400` but it does not show anything in my console. Not sure if I am forgetting anything or I have it setup wrong, but nothing is being passed back I am assuming.

**JQuery:**

```
$(".modalPathContentBtn").on("click", function(event) {

                getSecondQuery();

            });

            function getSecondQuery() {

                var search2 = {
                    "dtoTiername" : "Test"

                }

                $.ajax({
                    type : "POST",
                    contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    dataType : 'json',
                    url : "/ajax/mqlGetSecondQuery",
                    data : JSON.stringify(search2),
                    success : function(result) {

                        console.log("It works: " + result);

                    }

                });
            }
```

**Java:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ajax/mqlGetSecondQuery", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String sendSecondQuery(@RequestBody TestApp mTestApp, HttpServletRequest request) {
        String pathVal = mTestApp.getDtoTiername();

        System.out.println("Test of if it is getting to this part of the code");

return "randomString";


    }
```

Comment: Which SpringBoot starter (or starters) have you used?

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned your request is failing with a status code of 400 which would mean the `success` of your ajax request would not get called since the request has not succeeded. You need to add a fail handler. It would look something like this.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  dataType: 'json',
  url: "/ajax/mqlGetSecondQuery",
  data: JSON.stringify(search2),
  success: function(result) {
    console.log("It works: " + result);
  },
  fail: function(err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
});
```

This may not be exact syntax, but the idea here is that you have a fail handler

Comment: So its the weirdest thing, but I added your suggestion and still nothing shows. It is a 200 result code and the simple ```system.out.println()``` in my java works but the ```console.log()``` still doesn't show either the success or error.